# Proof of Sieve Method

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation

Here is the proof of Sieve Method on my professor's notes:

> Let $E$ be a given set and for all $S \subseteq E$,  let $f(S)$ and $g(S)$
> be the number of ways to build structures of $f$ and  $g$ respectively
> on $S$. Assume that for any $T \subseteq E$, we have
>
> $g(T) = \sum_{S \subseteq T}$ $f(S)$  (*)
>
> Thus one can obtain:
>
> $f(T) = \sum_{S \subseteq T} (-1)^{|T-S|} g(S)$ (**)

**Proof**

The proof starts with saying that it's enough to show the closure of $f(T)$ in (**) satisfies (*). I don't understand why showing the closure satisfying (**) will result in a correlation between $f(T)$ and $g(S)$ in summation form. I also don't understand why we chose to show the closure satisfies (**)?

Also, what does it mean to build structures of $f$ and $g$ on S? Does it mean defining $f$ and $g$ on the set S, or does it have a different meaning?

I am totally lost on how to prove this method. I would appreciate any hints, helps, or a completely different approach to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

This is Example 3.8.3 in Richard Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics ([https://www.ms.uky.edu/~sohum/putnam/enu_comb_stanley.pdf](https://www.ms.uky.edu/%7Esohum/putnam/enu_comb_stanley.pdf)).

In particular, this is the statement of the Mobius inversion formula for the poset consisting of subsets of $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$, ordered by the subset relation $\subseteq$.

Comment: Thank you, but I haven't yet learned about the Mobius inversion formula.